# How to specify with multiple objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, function

So I'm trying to make a code that allows me to change the image once I hover over it.

The initial code works. But I have 72 other images to go through with this feature. I'm trying to call each one individually so I don't have to repeat so much code.

I want a simple html code like

```
<img id="seal" src="img/seal/dantalion.png" onmouseover="rollover(dantalion)" 
onmouseout="rollaway(dantalion)" />
<img id="seal" src="img/seal/vassago.png" onmouseover="rollover(vassago)" 
onmouseout="rollaway(vassago)" />
```

Here is the code that works.

```
function rollover(img) {img.src = "img/seal/hover/vassago.png";}
function rollaway(img) {img.src = "img/seal/vassago.png";}
```

Here is what I want to do. Keep in mind please, I'm new to this sort of thing.

```
function rollover() {
dantalion.src = "img/seal/hover/dantalion.png";
vassago.src = "img/seal/hover/vassago.png";
}
function rollaway() {
dantalion.src = "img/seal/dantalion.png";
vassago.src = "img/seal/vassago.png";
}
```

How do I individually call the object in the HTML code?

Comment: Post the object that you have containing the images

Comment: Have you considered using event delegation so that you'd only need a single listener to handle them all?

Comment: @itodd Im not sure what you mean, sorry. my terms are rough so I may have used Object wrong.

Comment: @skirtle Do you have a link where I can learn this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple solution to your problem. On `mouseover` of the wrapper div `#images` we check if you are hovering an image and if so, update the image src with the hover url.

On `mouseout` or if you hover on a different image the images are reset back to the original src

```js
var images = document.getElementById('images');
var prevEl;

function resetImages() {
  if (prevEl) {
    prevEl.src = prevEl.src.replace('/hover', '');
    prevEl = null;
  }
}
  
images.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  resetImages();
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "IMG") {
    prevEl = e.target;
    e.target.src = e.target.src.replace('/seal', '/seal/hover');
  }
});

images.addEventListener('mouseout', resetImages);
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img src="img/seal/dantalion.png">
  <img src="img/seal/vassago.png">
</div>
```

Comment: so im trying this but it doesnt work. do i need to include a certain library?
I pasted the code into my script.js file

Comment: You will need to move your script.js to the bottom of the `body`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using event delegation. I've tried to use only core JS APIs because you didn't mention any libraries but if you were using a library there's a good chance it would be able to do some of this for you.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        cls = target.classList;
    
    if (!cls.contains('seal')) {
        return;
    }
    
    cls.add('seal-over');
    target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML.replace('/seal/', '/seal/hover/');
});

document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        cls = target.classList;
    
    if (!cls.contains('seal')) {
        return;
    }
    
    cls.remove('seal-over');
    target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML.replace('/hover', '');
});
```

```css
.seal {
    border: 1px dotted #777;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

.seal-over {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="seal">img/seal/dantalion.png</div>
<div class="seal">img/seal/vassago.png</div>
```

While my example changes the `innerHTML` you would change the `src` instead - I didn't have your images so I couldn't easily use `img` tags. The `id` attribute has to be unique so I've changed it to using a `class` instead. Adding the `seal-over` class isn't required, I just thought it made the example more interesting: you'd probably use a CSS `:hover` pseudo-class for that if this were real code.

One of many guides to delegation, you can find others with a quick search online:

https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

The idea is to add a single listener on an element higher up the tree. Events propagate up so you can react to events on descendent elements. The event `target` refers to the element on which the actual event occurred. The code checks whether this element is one of the elements we care about and then makes the changes accordingly.

Comment: so i should change target.innerHTML to target.src?

Comment: Yes. I chose not to use `<img>` tags in my example because I don't have your images and I wanted to ensure the example actually runs cleanly when you click 'Run code snippet'. For you it would be `<img>` and `src` rather than `<div>` and `innerHTML`.

Comment: I tried this after changing the code and it isnt working. 
       <img class="seal" src="img/seal/vassago.png">

Comment: also, i didnt add the css. should i?

Comment: My example is a fully runnable demo, if you click the 'Run code snippet' button you'll be able to see it in action. Without the CSS it would have been difficult to understand the demo, that's the only reason I included it. I highly recommend studying the code and making sure that you understand it before you try to apply it to your own application. MDN is a good place to start, e.g. `classList` is explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList My guess would be it isn't working because you haven't updated all 4 places where the code mentions `innerHTML`.

Comment: so i took all of this. made a blank document. and then applied everything inline. still doesnt work. i thought maybe it was because a part of my code broke it. but by itself. it wont change the text. there must be a library im missing here.

I didnt change anything in the blank document.

Comment: To diagnose the problem further I suggest adding some console logging to each of the handlers to see whether they are getting called at all. You can also use the browser's debug tools to step through the handlers. Browser dev tools have the ability to set breakpoints and you can also include the word `debugger` on a line by itself to trigger debugging.

Comment: ok. i debugged it. says "Cannot read property 'addEventListener'"

Comment: My guess would be that you've put the code above the `<body>` tag so `document.body` doesn't exist yet. You can either move the `<script>` tag down to the bottom of the page or use something like an `onload` event to wait until the page is ready.

Comment: You are correct!!! Ok. I'm gonna take this apart and apply it to my code.

Comment: Yes! It finally works. Thank you soooo much. This has given me a headache for 4 hrs now. Phew!!